# Render epub format document WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, rendering, epub, windows-phone-7.1

I'm need render epub document which size 700kb - 1.5Mb. Into WPF I'm using Flow Document Reader. I did not find this control in Windows Phone 7.1 SDK.
What can replace it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone does not include a FlowDocument control or native support for the epub format.

This leaves you with 2 options:
1. write your own parser and renderer for the ePub format.
2. convert the file to a format which is easier to render.

I'd recommend option 2.
You may get some milage from using [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) for the conversion.

Comment: To convert to html and render into WebBrowser, for example? Or perhaps a better solution?

Comment: @Mageno that's one way but you need to be aware of the possible differences with rendering content in the WebBrowser control.